# how to reflect primefaces live pie chart when new data inserted into database

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2

I am new to PrimeFaces. I would like to seek the example or tutorial that can guide on how to make a simple live pie chart when new data inserted into database.

For example, when a data inserted into database, the pie chart would get the value from database and it would reflected on pie chart.

I got the sample from this prime faces website but that sample is without database value.
[PrimeFaces simple live chart](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/chart/live.xhtml)

I am using PrimeFaces, jsf2.2, spring-hibernate & mysql for my small project.
Anyone can help where can I get any sample or tutorial can refer?
Thanks in advance[Snip the sample chart from primefaces.org](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4D2Bg.png)

Comment: Break down you problen in manageable parts

Comment: What I mean is that in the example they update the model each time with new values. So if you are able to populate the model initially from a database, I assume you can also populate it again. That way, this question is not java-se, nor mysql (nor database) nor jsf-2.2 or even jsf-2 related. Just a plain PrimeFaces issue (and effectively not even that, just some basic programming thing)

Answer (score 0):

This is really vague, but you can write a method to get value (example sum or count from db) . then in the bean like the example only the first two values would change.

```
public PieChartModel getLivePieModel() {
    int random1 = abstractFacade.countCandidate(candidate1); // Method to get data from db
    int random2 = abstractFacade.countCandidate(candidate2); // Method to get data from db

    livePieModel.getData().put("Candidate 1", random1);
    livePieModel.getData().put("Candidate 2", random2);

    livePieModel.setTitle("Votes");
    livePieModel.setLegendPosition("ne");

    return livePieModel;
```

}

The xhtml will stay the same as the demo